# Why do I need to "use std" in a module but not at the root of my crate?

Tags: rust

I have the following code in `main.rs`

```
fn util_function() -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
    Ok(String::from("OK"))
}

fn main() {
    let a = util_function().unwrap();
}
```

I split `main.rs` into two files:

```
// util.rs
fn util_function() -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
    Ok(String::from("OK"))
}
```

and

```
// main.rs

mod util;

fn main() {
    let a = util::util_function().unwrap();
}
```

The problem that `util.rs` has a compilation error:

```
pub fn util_function(mut stream: &TcpStream) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
  |                                                            ^^^ Use of     undeclared type or module `std`
```

So why should I add `using std;` to the `utils.rs` while it is not necessary in `main.rs`?

Comment: Um....doesn't your question answer itself? I don't know Rust, but you're using `std::io::Error` in `utils.rs` and the error is telling you the compiler doesn't know what that is without the `using std;`. Presumably `using std;` would tell it what that is, vaguely like `include` in C and C++, `import` in Java, etc. So....?

Comment: Not really, I don't need to do this in `main.rs`

Comment: Look at your (second) `main.rs`: Where do you see `std::io::Error`? (Or anything else from `std`?) Answer: You don't. :-) So the compiler doesn't need to know what it is when compiling `main.rs`.